# Django model form this field is required

Tags: django, modelform

I am new to Django. Trying to add data to database using ModelForm. But getting an error "This field is required.."

My model:

```
class Docstest(models.Model):
uploader =models.ForeignKey("auth.User",blank=False,null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nameOfApplicant = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    serviceRequestedName= models.ForeignKey(ServicesOffered,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,null=False)
    nameOfDocument = models.ForeignKey(DocumentsRequired,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,null=False)
    documentFile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%M', blank = False, null = False)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nameOfDocument)+str(self.uploader)
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Docstest
    fields = ["uploader", "nameOfApplicant","serviceRequestedName","nameOfDocument","documentFile",]
    labels = {"uploader":"uploader", "nameOfApplicant":"nameOfApplicant","serviceRequestedName":"serviceRequestedName","nameOfDocument":"nameOfDocument","documentFile":"documentFile",}
```

my html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block columncard %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Form</legend>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

There is a error "This field is required". Data not saved in Database.
Help.

Comment: Well, wah field is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag in your template